# Popups with just HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

is there any way to do a popup with just HTML and CSS and to have it appear on every 20th visit in total, to any/all pages on a website please?

Comment: No, you would need some server side code for that. HTML and CSS are purely client side.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do this using just HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway you should use javascript. You can set counter into localStorage to get when user visited your site 20 times. And you can show/hide your popup with javascript only.

Comment: ok what if the user clears browser history and all cookies everything. Will it still be the exact nth visit.

Comment: No it wouldn't, doing a cache sweep will delete the local storage of the site resetting your counter to 0

Comment: @Manish we do not look at such cases - because user can delete all info with which we can identify him (if we don't talk about libraries like fingerprint.js)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, there is no way to accomplish this with just HTML and CSS. You would need some server-side language to track page visits. Or, you *could* use cookies or sessionStorage/localStorage with JavaScript. However it's not the most reliable way to keep statistics.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you could do a pop up just using HTML and CSS. The only thing you could do is use an overlay. But even than if you wanted to pop open the message you would still have to use Javascript or some server side language. There are some good ideas on google which will point you to the right direction.

All the best.
Cheers :)